# Import CSV into a table with rake file

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to write a rake file that imports a CSV file into the table, my code is.

```
CSV.foreach("#{pathToCSV}",:col_sep => ";", :headers => true) do |row|
  "#{SetNameModel}".create! (row.to_hash)
end
```

but I get

```
undefined method `create!'
```

When I thy to add a record manually in the rails console with the create! method, it works fine. What do I have to fix to make it parse the CSV and add it to the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `create!` on a string. Instead, you want to call it on the class that has the name of that string. Try this:

```
Object.const_get(SetNameModel).create!
```